# BufferedReader then write to txt file?

Tags: java, file, io, bufferedreader, printwriter

Is it possible to use BufferedReader to read from a text file, and then while buffered reader is reading, at the same time it also storing the lines it read to another txt file using PrintWriter?

Comment: Yes, it sure is possible..  Should I enter that as an answer?

Comment: Why not just use two `FileChannel`s and use `.transfer{From,To}()`?

Comment: @fge umm do you mind to provide some example on how to use it?

Comment: Depends on what version of Java you use. If it's Java 7, it will be much shorter.

Comment: @fge ummm, I'm using 7 I think.

Comment: OK, other question: do you really need to read line by line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use Java 7 and want to copy one file directly into another, it is as simple as:

```
final Path src = Paths.get(...);
final Path dst = Paths.get(...);
Files.copy(src, dst);
```

If you want to read line by line and write again, grab `src` and `dst` the same way as above, then do:

```
final BufferedReader reader;
final BufferedWriter writer;
String line;

try (
    reader = Files.newBufferedReader(src, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(dst, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
) {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        doSomethingWith(line);
        writer.write(line);
        // must do this: .readLine() will have stripped line endings
        writer.newLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To directly answer your question:

you can, and you can also use BufferedWriter to do so.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Filepath")));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("Filepath")));
String l;
while((l=br.readLine())!=null){

    ... do stuff ...

    bw.write("what you did");

}

bw.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to copy without inspecting the data, then it's a one liner:
[IOUtils.copy(reader, printWriter);](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.Reader,%20java.io.Writer%29)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Open the `BufferedReader`, and then create a `PrintWriter`. You can read from the stream as you write to the writer.