# How can I store the results I received from the server to a textfile

Tags: java, sockets

Can anybody help me with this here.  I am a newbie and I am working on a network application where I have to create a socket connection to the IP address and port that they already given  me and then send XML message to the socket and finally include the ReadMe.txt file where I will save what I have received from the server.  Here's my code

```
private static Socket socket;

public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        socket = new Socket( "196.37.22.179", 9011);

        //Send the message to the server
        //PrintStream outstrm = null;
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

        String str;
        str = "<request>";
        str += "<EventType>Authentication</EventType>";
        str += "<event>";
        str += "<UserPin>12345</UserPin>";
        str += "<DeviceId>12345</DeviceId>";
        str += "<DeviceSer>ABCDE</DeviceSer>";
        str += "<DeviceVer>ABCDE</DeviceVer>";
        str += "<TransType>Users</TransType>";
        str += "</event></request>";
        bw.write(str);
        bw.flush();
        System.out.println("Message sent to the server......! ");

        //Get the return message from the server
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);        
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        //Closing the socket
        try
        {
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BufferedReader then write to txt file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622324/bufferedreader-then-write-to-txt-file)

Comment: I don't think so because this is serverside and the writing to file should be client side (?)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code to store results from server in file

```
//Get the return message from the server
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("ReadMe.txt"));
int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
```